# Class and Method deprecation warning without marking deprecated

Tags: java, deprecated

In my workspace Eclipse gives deprecated warning on one class and it's methods without any deprecated annotation. Not sure where are they coming from. Any hint?

Note: I checked the class and it's hierarchy, nothing is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Have you cleaned all projects in your workspace? It could be a class file that hasn't been rebuilt automatically for some reason. In addition, you could be extending the wrong version of a base class, or importing the wrong class (JUnit 4, for example, tends to import the deprecated `junit.framework.*` package instead of the correct `org.junit.*`)

Comment: Thanks! Probably that's the cause, i just set up a new workspace by taking the same code from repo and it doesn't have those warnings. However in the old workspace even if i delete all the class files, it doesn't help.

Comment: Well, most times it's not enough to just delete the class files, since the editor just slaps the output from the compiler over the source file based on character offset. Unless you tell the editor to tell the compiler to rebuild those files, it probably won't show, since in the first place, it's not rebuilding the class file automatically upon save like it should.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no other option to get rid of those warnings in Eclipse?

Comment: Basically, you need to figure out why Eclipse wasn't able to rebuild the file. Either it had enough errors to force the compiler to give up on background compilation the last time you saved, or some dependency of the given file failed to build, making the compiler jump the shark. Generally, doing a clean of all projects, rebuilding requisite JARs, and making sure you don't have errors elsewhere are the main culprits. Manually deleting build artifacts is a good way to make Eclipse trip over its own expectations and cause this, and cleaning all projects is how you'd address that.